# A problem in transitivity of set

Tags: set-theory, axioms

> Let $D$ be a transitive set with the following property :
>     $$\forall a\in D:\quad a\subseteq B\,\Longrightarrow a\in B$$
>   Prove that $D\subseteq B$.

I think there will be needed *axiom of regularity* in my attempt, but don't know how to apply it :

By contrary, suppose $a_0\in D$, but $a_0\notin B$. Therefore $a_0\nsubseteq B$. Thus, there exists $a_1\in a_0\in D$, such that $a_1\notin B$. By repeating this procedure $\alpha$ times, Now look at $D-B$ :

$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
a_{\alpha}\in\cdots\in a_2\in a_1\in a_0\in D-B\\
\forall\alpha:a_{\alpha}\in D-B\quad(\text{by transfinite induction!})
\end{array}\right.$$

Now the *rank* of sequence $\{a_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in Ord}$ is decreasing without end (But it's not precise anyway!).

---

Any help for formulation and making precise is so appreciated. (Or any approach other than regularity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing transfinite induction directly, just use the (already known, I hope) fact that all sets have rank:

Suppose $D\not\subseteq B$. Then $D\setminus B$ is nonempty and therefore has an element $x$ of least rank.

All elements of $x$ are in $D$ (because $D$ is transitive), and therefore they are also in $B$ (because $x$ has least rank among elements outside $B$). Therefore $x\subseteq B$ ...

---

Some sort of regularity or foundation is necessary, because there are non-well-founded counterexamples. For example, given an appropriate anti-foundation axiom, we can let $D=\{D\}$ and $B=\varnothing$. Then the premise is true, but $D\not\subseteq\varnothing$.

Comment: I'm do not completely know ranks but doesn't existence of least rank need regularity ?

Comment: @FardadPouran: Well, ranks are by definition always ordinals, so once you _have_ ranks, it is trivial that there's a least one. However, you need regularity to have ranks for everything, and if you don't have some kind of regularity the property you're trying to prove isn't true as the $D=\{D\}$ example shows.

Comment: Oh yes. i got the point ... thank you